# Is there a way to export data from Bigquery to Facebook Ads without using any third party ETL tools and Facebook SDK?

Tags: api, facebook, google-bigquery

We are using a 3rd party program called 'Zapier' to export some offline conversion data from Bigquery to Facebook Ads on a daily basis. However, I was investigating if we can have an in-house solution to send data thru a Facebook API but a simple google search and asking a few friends did not give me any results.

Comment: Currently it's not possible to directly export data from Bigquery to Facebook Ads without using third party tools. If you want this feature to be implemented, you can open a new [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) on the issue tracker describing your requirement.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if we can export data to Facebook from elsewhere or just a .csv file programmatically?